# Python - Is there a way to put a function in a function and not get "TypeError: 'int' object is not callable"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, module

I am making a multiplayer dice rolling game where you get points depending on what you rolled. I am trying to put a function inside a function however this doesn't work due to typeerror.

I searched up online how to reduce interaction between function to try remove one function from the other however there were no answers. Also have asked my peers and teacher about this but they didn't know either.

```
import random

playerPoints = []
minPlayers = 2
players = 0
maxscore = 100
amountOfDice = 2
gameRound = 0
toRoll = ""
die1 = random.randint(1, 6)
die2 = random.randint(1, 6)

def setPlayers():
    while True:
        players = input("How many players are playing?\n")
        if players.isdigit():
            players = int(players)
            if minPlayers <= players:
                for i in range(players):
                    playerPoints.append(0)
                return players

def diceroll(player, amountOfDice, die1, die2):
    throw = 0
    print("Player {0}s turn:".format(player + 1))
    for i in range(amountOfDice):
        roll = 0
        while roll != toRoll:
            roll = input("Press enter to roll both dice")
            if roll == toRoll:
                print("Player {0} has thrown {1} and {2}".format(player + 1, i + 1, die1, die2))
                break
        points()

def cont():
    cont = input("Would you like to continue or stop? Press [C] to continue or press [S] to stop.")
    if cont == "c":
        points()
    elif cont == "s":
        print("You have successfully cashed in " + str(points) + " points. Well done!")
        playerPoints[players] += points

    playerPoints[player] += throw
    print("Player {0}s score is now: {1}".format(player + 1, playerPoints[player]))
    return throw

def checkWin(maxscore):
    for player in range(players):
        if (playerPoints[player] >= maxscore):
            print("Player {0} wins!".format(player + 1))
            return True

    return False

def points():
    while die1 != 1 or die2 != 1 and cont == "c":
        for i in playerPoints:
            global points
            points = 0
        if die1 == 1 and die2 == 1:
            print("That means you store " + str(double1) + " points.")
            points += double1
            cont()
        elif die1 == die2:
            print("That means you store " + str((die1 + die2)*2) + " points.")
            points += (die1 + die2)*2
            cont()
        elif die1 != die2:
            print("That means you store " + str(die1 + die2) + " points.")
            points += die1 + die2
            cont()
        elif die1 == 1 or die2 == 2:
            print("Unlucky! You have rolled " + str(die1) + " and " + str(die2) + ". Since you rolled a 1, your turn has ended. You have lost all stored points so far, and you lose " + str(die1 + die2) + " points.")
            points -= (die1 + die2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    players = setPlayers()
    while True:
        gameRound += 1
        print("Round: {0}".format(gameRound))
        for i in range(players):
            diceroll(i, amountOfDice, die1, die2)
        if (checkWin(maxscore)):
            break

def players(numberOfPlayers):
    numberOfPlayers = 0
    while numberOfPlayers not in (str(i) for i in range (minPlayers,maxPlayers)):
        numberOfPlayers = int(numberOfPlayers)
        for i in range(numberOfPlayers):
            playerPoints["score{}".format(i+1)] = 0
        return numberOfPlayers
```

Please paste the code into python IDLE or something to try the code out.

So basically it starts off by asking how many players. I input 2, as this is the minimum.

It then asks to press enter to roll die, and this works perfectly fine.

It finally asks if I would like to continue or stop, and when I press c to continue, it says TypeError.

If I press s to stop, it says IndexError.

I need this code to continue for the rest of the code to work, or for me to fix any mistakes in my code.

Comment: Consider using separate names for your functions and variables. Using the same name does shadowing and harms readability.

Comment: Yeah sorry about the messiness of the code. I just have no originality ahaha but thats not the problem atm

Comment: Originality or not, even a simple suffix such as `_var` or `_func` will do. And how is this not the problem [to the TypeError]? The error clearly tells us that calling `point()` in the `cont()` is calling an `int`, similar to doing `3()`. This implies that `point` is an `int` and the only place where this is set is in the `points` function itself (e.g. `points = 0`). Disambiguate your variables, rethink your program structure and flow, and these sort of errors will be made less often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first error when you press c is caused because of same variable and function name 'points'. And second error is caused due to the list running out of index which can be fixed by subtracting the index by one.

Here is a fixed code,

```
import random

playerPoints = []
minPlayers = 2
players = 0
maxscore = 100
amountOfDice = 2
gameRound = 0
toRoll = ""
die1 = random.randint(1, 6)
die2 = random.randint(1, 6)

def setPlayers():
    while True:
        players = input("How many players are playing?\n")
        if players.isdigit():
            players = int(players)
            if minPlayers <= players:
                for i in range(players):
                    playerPoints.append(0)
                return players

def diceroll(player, amountOfDice, die1, die2):
    throw = 0
    print("Player {0}s turn:".format(player + 1))
    for i in range(amountOfDice):
        roll = 0
        while roll != toRoll:
            roll = input("Press enter to roll both dice")
            if roll == toRoll:
                print("Player {0} has thrown {1} and {2}".format(player + 1, i + 1, die1, die2))
                break
        func_points()

def cont():
    cont = input("Would you like to continue or stop? Press [C] to continue or press [S] to stop.")
    if cont == "c":
        func_points()
    elif cont == "s":
        print("You have successfully cashed in " + str(points) + " points. Well done!")
        print (playerPoints, players)
        playerPoints[players - 1] += points

    playerPoints[players - 1] += throw
    print("Player {0}s score is now: {1}".format(player + 1, playerPoints[player]))
    return throw

def checkWin(maxscore):
    for player in range(players):
        if (playerPoints[player] >= maxscore):
            print("Player {0} wins!".format(player + 1))
            return True

    return False

def func_points():
    while die1 != 1 or die2 != 1 and cont == "c":
        for i in playerPoints:
            global points
            points = 0
        if die1 == 1 and die2 == 1:
            print("That means you store " + str(double1) + " points.")
            points += double1
            cont()
        elif die1 == die2:
            print("That means you store " + str((die1 + die2)*2) + " points.")
            points += (die1 + die2)*2
            cont()
        elif die1 != die2:
            print("That means you store " + str(die1 + die2) + " points.")
            points += die1 + die2
            cont()
        elif die1 == 1 or die2 == 2:
            print("Unlucky! You have rolled " + str(die1) + " and " + str(die2) + ". Since you rolled a 1, your turn has ended. You have lost all stored points so far, and you lose " + str(die1 + die2) + " points.")
            points -= (die1 + die2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    players = setPlayers()
    while True:
        gameRound += 1
        print("Round: {0}".format(gameRound))
        for i in range(players):
            diceroll(i, amountOfDice, die1, die2)
        if (checkWin(maxscore)):
            break

def players(numberOfPlayers):
    numberOfPlayers = 0
    while numberOfPlayers not in (str(i) for i in range (minPlayers,maxPlayers)):
        numberOfPlayers = int(numberOfPlayers)
        for i in range(numberOfPlayers):
            playerPoints["score{}".format(i+1)] = 0
        return numberOfPlayers
```

For future reference, it's a good programming practice to give appropriate variable and function names in order to avoid confusion and worse, bugs.

Comment: "_it's seldom a good programming practice_" Hmm... 'seldom' means 'rarely', which doesn't seem to be the right word here. On another note, 1) `cont` and `cont()` could also use some renaming; 2) `player` vs. `players`... might want to clarify that with another sentence or two.

Comment: My gosh. Sorry for the misuse of the word. I edited it. 
I only renamed the things required to rectify OP's original error.

Answer (score 0):

playerPoints = [0, 0]
player = 2

By doing playerPoints[player], you are trying to access the 3rd element which does not exist. List indexing starts at 0.

You could do playerPoints[player - 1]

Comment: I just tried that out, unfortunately it doesn't work :(

Comment: @Anonymous "it doesn't work" is a bit vague. This answer *does* address the index error. What doesn't work? Why and how?